# WordPress Contact Form 7 принимает некорректный телефон

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как в Contact Form 7 исключить ввод короткого и длинного телефона?

Comment: А какой телефон вы считаете подходящей длины?

Comment: Согласно [ссылке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) для номеров географических зон допускается 15 цифр без учета кода страны.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно заглянуть в документацию https://contactform7.com/text-fields/

`[tel your-tel minlength:10 maxlength:10 "123-456-7890"]`